# R - list of identically named data frames: select on variable name

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of data frames with the same structure (same variable-names, same number of observations). Something like

```
df1<-data.frame(a=c(1,2),condition=c(TRUE,FALSE))
df2<-data.frame(a=c(1,2),condition=c(TRUE,TRUE))

df.list<-list(df1,df2)
```

And I want to automate (mainly make the code independent of the number dataframes in the list) things like

```
DF$Condition = df.list[[1]]$Condition + df.list[[2]]$Condition
```

or

```
DF$Condition = all(df.list[[1]]$Condition, df.list[[2]]$Condition  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` with `+` after subsetting the 'condition' column

```
Reduce(`+`, lapply(df.list, `[`, 'condition'))
```

and for the second case

```
Reduce(function(...) identical(...), lapply(df.list, `[`, 'condition'))
```

Comment: Something that complicates the case: DF$Condition is now a data.frame itself, so you nee DF$Condition<-unlist(Reduce(...)) to work with it properly